# Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse: [!] Missing required information to submit for external testing - Missing requied data

Tags: testflight, xcode11, fastlane

I'm facing this issue, while running fastlane pilot command in terminal. How should i use this " beta_app_review_info" as a parameter? what value need's to be added?

Here's the command i've tried to run but getting failed with "beta_app_review_info' value must be a Hash! Found String instead."

fastlane pilot upload --username="XXX@gmail.com" --verbose --changelog "$(cat changelog1.txt)" --distribute_external true --groups="Users" --ipa="build/Release-iphoneos/some.ipa" --beta_app_review_info “contact_email: "XXXXX@gmail.com",contact_first_name: "test",contact_last_name: "user",contact_phone: "XXXXXX",demo_account_name: "testuser@gmail.com",demo_account_password: "XXXX"

looks like beta_app_review_info is not included as parameter in Fastlane pilot. Can someone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: I got it working by add beta_app_review_info details in Fastfile inside fastlane directory and then i ran command fastlane beta .

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Probably, AppStore start to require extra meta data. 
Adding beta_app_review_info did fix the problem. 
Sample:

```
upload_to_testflight(
  beta_app_review_info: {
    contact_email: "email@email.com",
    contact_first_name: "Connect",
    contact_last_name: "API",
    contact_phone: "5558675309",
    demo_account_name: "demo@email.com",
    demo_account_password: "connectapi",
    notes: "this is review note for the reviewer <3 thank you for reviewing"
  },
  localized_app_info: {
    "default": {
      feedback_email: "default@email.com",
      marketing_url: "https://example.com/marketing-defafult",
      privacy_policy_url: "https://example.com/privacy-defafult",
      description: "Default description",
    },
    "en-GB": {
      feedback_email: "en-gb@email.com",
      marketing_url: "https://example.com/marketing-en-gb",
      privacy_policy_url: "https://example.com/privacy-en-gb",
      description: "en-gb description",
    }
  },
  localized_build_info: {
    "default": {
      whats_new: "Default changelog",
    },
    "en-GB": {
      whats_new: "en-gb changelog",
    }
  }
)
```

Reference: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_testflight/